# Why is an explicit lifetime needed for this FnMut

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime

The following example does compile ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae7928d50a5b8e6c9c6beb6b0deb1744)):

```
use std::future::Future;

static API: Api = Api;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Api;

async fn with_api<'a, F, Fut>(f: F) -> Fut::Output
where
    F: FnOnce(&'a Api) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    f(&API).await
}

fn main() {
    with_api(|api| async move {
        println!("{:?}", api);
    });
}
```

However, when removing the explicit lifetime `'a` here I get this error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:20
   |
17 |       with_api(|api| async move {
   |  _______________----_^
   | |               |  |
   | |               |  return type of closure is impl std::future::Future
   | |               has type `&'1 Api`
18 | |         println!("{:?}", api);
19 | |     });
   | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

I have two questions regarding that:

1. What is the problem here? Specifically, what is the lifetime `'2`?
2. Why is adding the explicit lifetime fixed the compilation and how is it different from the inferred lifetime?

Comment: The unexplained reference to the lifetime `'2` in the error message seems like a compiler bug.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74497) on rust-lang repo.